# Why won't this code read the file?

Tags: java, android, macos, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that reads from a file named `Clients` and then through a for loop writes to the console. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class ShowOccupancy{
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws FileNotFoundException{ 
        Scanner diskScanner = 
                new Scanner (new File("Clients"));              
        out.print("Room Number");
        out.print("/t");
        out.println("Guests");
        for (int roomNum=0; roomNum<10; roomNum++)
        {
            out.print(roomNum);
            out.print("/t");
            out.print(diskScanner.nextInt());                   
        }
        diskScanner.close();
    }                               
}
```

Here are the errors in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Clients (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at ShowOccupancy.main(ShowOccupancy.java:11)
```

And I created a `Clients` file for the java project.

Comment: Well look at what the exception says - the file doesn't exist. Perhaps you're running it from the wrong directory?

Comment: and where is that file??? sdcard, internal memory, inside the apk file?

Comment: Copy the file into classpath Or provide complete location of file

Comment: @sunrise76 Why copy to classpath? The classpath is not searched when trying to open a file.

Comment: I mean to say "copy the file into one of the locations mentioned in classpath" or provide complete file location.

Comment: @sunrise76, that also does not make sense. if you use a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the CWD, and to the CWD only.. as Andreas said, it is not related to the classpath.

Comment: I always keep files in one of classpath directories and never depend on current directory so that I can run my application from any location on the machine.

Comment: and I use  this.getClass().getResource related APIs

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of how to read text files, hope it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("FILE-PATH-HERE/clients.txt"));

        //Prints lines
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        }

        //Prints tokens
        /*
         while (reader.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(reader.next());
         }
         */
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Print error
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```